# Hide overflow of video background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide the over flow of the video to be the same size as the container, I have tried overflow: hidden; on the container but it has no effect.

Basically when you look at the site, I am trying to achieve the video to not resize its aspect ratio, but just hide the portion the overflows off the container.

```
    <header id="welcome-section">
        <div>
            <p id="hello">Hello, my name is</p>
            <h1 id="ryan">Ryan Thacker</h1>
            a href="#section-a" class="button">Learn More</a>
        </div>
        <video autoplay muted loop id="bgVideo">
           <source src="images/Beach.webm" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </header>
```

```
    #welcome-section {
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0 20px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    }
    
    #bgVideo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px; 
      left: 0px; 
      min-width: 100%; 
      min-height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can add `overflow-x: hidden` to `body`.

Comment: The issue now is it worked for the desktop view, but in mobile it did not do anything, this is really weird. I updated the website for you to see.

Comment: ok, let's act a bit more complicated. This should help: https://jsfiddle.net/n5sq6j37/3/

Answer (score 0):

Hi if I understand correctly your questions you wanted to the video width to be as much as your #welcome-section -s width. I added some css lines and it resolved the problem.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#welcome-section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

#bgVideo {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Close to what I was wanting but I appreciate the help!